# How to keep div size when showing submenu on top Tailwind and React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Using Tailwind an React - When clicking on an icon I show a submenu but it happens that when the container div is shown it becomes bigger in its height automatically.

How can I display this submenu on top of the other elements so that it doesn't make its container div bigger? I tried with fixed but it moves from the place I require it to be displayed.

This is the code:

The table where I show the submenu when clicking:

```
<div className="flex flex-wrap m-5 mx-auto w-full pr-2 pl-2">
    <div className="w-full px-4">
    <div className="flex flex-wrap">
        <div className="flex flex-col min-w-0 break-words w-full mb-6 shadow-lg rounded bg-white">
        <div className="block w-full overflow-x-auto">
            <table className="items-center w-full bg-transparent border-collapse">
            <thead className="bg-sky-50">
                <tr>
                <th className="px-6 align-middle border border-solid py-3 text-xs uppercase border-l-0 border-r-0 whitespace-nowrap font-semibold bg-blueGray-50 text-blueGray-500 border-blueGray-100">
                    Opciones
                </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr className="hover:bg-slate-100">
                <td className="border-t-0 px-6 align-middle border-l-0 text-center border-r-0 text-xs whitespace-nowrap p-4">
                    <div>
                    <OptionsDropDown
                        showDropdown={showDropdown}
                        setShowDropdown={setShowDropdown}
                        dataDropDown={dataDropDown}
                    />
                    </div>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Menu Component, Here I have the icon and what I show when I click on it but it widens the parent div:

```
<div className="flex justify-center">
    <button
    ref={ref}
    className="flex items-center 
                text-black  py-2 px-2
                text-2xl hover:text-cyan-700"
    onClick={() => setShowDropdown(!showDropdown)}
    >
    <FiMoreVertical />
    </button>

    {showDropdown && (
    <div className="relative bg-white text-base z-50 py-2 rounded shadow-lg">
        {dataDropDown.map((option, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            <a href="" className="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-indigo-300">
            {option.edit}
            </a>
            <a href="" className="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-indigo-300">
            {option.delete}
            </a>
        </div>
        ))}
    </div>
    )}
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like right now on click, making the size of the parent div higher:

Here it is before clicking:

[image: submenu icon]

Clicking the container div makes it wide:

[image: open submenu]

Using abosulte on submenu

[image: using absolute]

Comment: You'll need to separate the divs so that one is *not* contained in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely looking for `absolute` positioning using a `relative` positioning on the direct parent so that the position of the absolute element is anchored to its immediate parent.

Something like this should work:

```
<div className="relative flex justify-center">
{/* NOTE: the relative positioning above */}

            <button ref={ref} 
                className="flex items-center 
                         text-black  py-2 px-2
                           text-2xl hover:text-cyan-700"
                onClick={ ()=> setShowDropdown(!showDropdown) }>
                <FiMoreVertical/>
            </button>
            
            {
                showDropdown && ( 
                    <div className="absolute right-0 top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 bg-white text-base z-50 py-2 rounded shadow-lg">
                        {/* which allows this to anchor */}
                        {
                            dataDropDown.map( (option, index) => (
                                <div key={index}>
                                    <a  href="" className="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-indigo-300">{option.edit}</a>
                                    <a  href="" className="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-indigo-300">{option.delete}</a>
                                </div>
                            ))
                        }
                    </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
```

although I expect you'll have to tweak it slightly to get the results that you want. It might also be worth looking into the `blur` event to automatically hide the popup once it loses focus.

Comment: It works but the dropdown is shown below the parent div and then hidden. attached screenshot

Comment: ah. sorry made a typo in my from-memory tailwind. corrected in edit. should have been '-translate-y-1/2' and not '-transform-y-/12'.

Comment: to fix the scrolling, you'll need to make sure that you're handling oversteps correctly. let me know if you can't get it & I'll make a codesandbox with how it should be done :D

Comment: Thank you thank you very much! It finally works, I spent hours with this problem. Thank you!